# Why EditText automatically merge all span in a word when typing?

Tags: android, spannablestring

I have a example :

```
 var ssb = SpannableStringBuilder("abcd")
 ssb.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
 ssb.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 2, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
 ssb.removeSpan(ssb.getSpans(2, 4, ForegroundColorSpan::class.java)[0])
 ssb.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 3, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
 text.text = ssb
```

I found that all span I set was merge into 1 as first span.
Before :
[image]

After input new character :

[image]

How to avoid this?

Comment: you can either disable text auto correction or reset the text in a textwatcher

Answer (score 0):

The last argument to `setSpan()` is a flag that controls the behavior of the span. You passed `Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE`, whose documentation says:

> Non-0-length spans of type SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE expand to include text inserted at their ending point but not at their starting point.

If you want your spans to stay fixed in place even when a user types into the `EditText`, then change your flag to be `Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE` instead.

Comment: I have changed it by using  Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE before but same behavior. This case, all the text will be blackout instead red

Comment: What api level / phone model are you testing on? I do not see this behavior when I try your code.

Comment: My device is Galaxy Tab A/ Android 7.0. I have just tested on virtual device API 16 and the color is OK. What different between them?